# Can I communicate with a slave BLE even if app is not running?

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I am developing an iOS application that communicates with  a slave BLE device. I know iOS will allow my app to run in background to communicate with BLE. What my doubt is that is there any way to turn on my app if there is any BLE near by? I mean even if my app is not running can I communicate with BLE? Like location service works,i.e., if the app registered for a significant location change alert then app will get automatically turned on when there is a significant location change even if app is not running.

I have searched a lot, but couldn't find any helpful documentation. Any help is greatly appreciated..

Comment: how will BLE get recognised? is it with `GPS` or `Bluetooth`? I think it should have something that will help to get recognised?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things here and I think you have to be careful with terminology. Let's first clarify "Not running". The app has 5 modes it can be in:

1. Foreground: the app is "live" and on the screen
2. Background - unlocked: the app is "live" but not on the screen. There is either another app on the screen (front) or possibly the user is on the home screen, browsing his/her apps, etc..
3. Background - locked: self explanatory
4. Terminated by user - still on device: The user has double clicked the home button and flicked your app up (iOS7) to close it.
5. Terminated by system - still on device: The app has been terminated by OS because of memory pressure (other apps needed the memory space).

Obviously, if the user has deleted the app from the device then there is nothing to discuss.

In option 4, the app is still on the device but will not relaunch any of its background services (BLE, location updates, etc..) until the user relaunches the app. This is new iOS7 behavior. If the user terminated the app then he/she does not want it running.

In option 5, because the user has not terminated the app; the OS will relaunch the app background services as it receives callbacks.

In order for an app to run in the background, it requires that you add the appropriate background modes to its plist or simply click on project (top left) and go to "Capabilities" and enable "Background modes" and the appropriate background mode. In your case: "Uses Bluetooth LE Accessories".

Now you seem to be looking for "Scanning" versus connecting and exchanging data and in my experience, scanning will only work in scenarios 1 and 2 and 5. Not 3. I have tried many times to get scanning to happen while phone is locked with no luck.

Now the way, fitbit etc... work in the background is that the app, scans, discovers services and characteristics and "setup updates" between the phone and accessory while the app is in the foreground. Once this setup is done, the "value of interest" updates (heart beat, etc..) can happen between the BLE acessory and the iOS device, in the background (locked and unlocked).

Hope this helps.